# Convert timestamp in seconds to timestamp in millseconds

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting this timestamp in a response I am adding to a dataframe. `1613065177.952422`

When I use unit='s' the time is correct if I use unit='ms' the time is all messed up, usually the date is 1970 and the time is wrong. So I'm assuming that means this timestamp is in seconds, I need to convert it to milliseconds.

I see the s to ms conversion is to divide my 1000 but when I tried taking the timestamp * 1000 I got a Value error: non convertible value, then a really really long number(too big to post here)

This is the code where I convert the timestamp using unit='s' using pandas I tried to make the time variable the ms conversion but that didn't work out too well..

```
time= df.timestamp * 1000
fdf.insert(1, 'time', pd.to_datetime(time, unit='s'))
```

Comment: why do u want to convert it into milliseconds?

Comment: And yes the default is `nanoseconds` mentioned in pandas documentation `unit str, default ‘ns’`

Comment: The project Im working on requires it, and Im aware ns is the default thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the datetime module:

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.now()
>>> date
datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 17, 16, 16, 34, 879683)
>>> date.second
34
>>> date.microsecond
879683
```

When you create a datetime object it will also give you the microsecond atribute. If you want miliseconds, just use the first three digits.
So you should have 34879 milliseconds for this example.

If you are using string data, you can can create datetime objects according to these instructions: https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/